# login system in java with username and password

Tags: java

I am really new in java. I have an assignment that include login system with 3 users. My problem is the program is keep looping. Where am I missing? Thanks.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String entryUsername;
    String username1 = "mimi";
    String username2 = "nurul";
    String username3 = "yaya";

    int entryPassword;
    int password1 = 7104;
    int password2 = 7116;
    int password3 = 7020;

    System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
    entryUsername = input.next();

    System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
    entryPassword = input.nextInt();

    while ( !(entryUsername.equals(username1)) || !
             (entryUsername.equals(username2)) || !
             (entryUsername.equals(username3)) 
             && (entryPassword == password1) || (entryPassword == password2) || (entryPassword == password3) ) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Username or Password");
        System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
        entryUsername = input.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
        entryPassword = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Logged In");
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You don't say where your program is looping. It shows that you didn't put enough effort into debugging it. If you want to be a good programmer you need to learn to debug your code. This site is not a substitute for logic and debugging skills. Also the more specific your question is the higher chances that you'll get an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop should be like this for one pair of `username` and `password` of string type:

```
while ( !( inputUsername.equals( username1 ) &&
           inputPassword.equals( password1 ) ) )
{
    // Again ask for username and password here...
}
```

But, that'll soon become cumbersome to write a lot of such conditions manually. Using `while` like that isn't a good idea at all. It'll soon become cumbersome. Alternatively, you can have arrays of usernames and passwords and use that to validate. Something like this (pseudo code -- kind of):

```
boolean isValidated = false;

while ( !isValidated )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_USERS; ++i )
    {
        if ( inputUsername.equals( arrayUsernames[i] ) &&
             inputPassword.equals( arrayPasswords[i] ) )
        {
            isValidated = true;
            break;
        }

        // Again ask for username and password
    }
}
```

It'll be more flexible and extendable that way.
You can use any other data structure of your choice for sequential validation.